# Apple iTunes App's Limitation

Tags: ios, ios6

I have an idea of an iPhone app that allow users to ring their phone for specific call even its on silent mode.
But problem is I don't know apple will allow it or not.
Is it possible for apple?

Comment: I think it's fine. I don't think there's a way to detect who's calling without invoking private APIs, though.

Comment: that mean i have to work hard. thanks. :)

Comment: Questions about Apple/iTunes policy are off-topic (and no one here can answer with authority, anyway). Please rephrase your question to be about programming, such as how to detect incoming calls from an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes,why not? i have used the application like this. its absolutely legal

Comment: do i need to take any permission from apple?

Comment: as per my information, you dont need to take permission for this

Comment: Thanks, atleast now i can ask it on dev center.